# do we have CSOM code to retrieve all lists under a site collection?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying hard to get details of all the lists from a SharePoint site collection and export to CSV.

I am trying to run remotely from my machine and it doesn't work. I am not an export CSOM guy so asking for help, please. 
I heard from someone that CSOM can run from anywhere and able to get info from SHarePoint 2013 server.

```
import-module C:\powershell\SharePointPnPPowerShell2013\3.16.1912.0\sharepointpnppowershell2013.psd1 -DisableNameChecking
 $username = "testing@domain.com"
 $password="Password"

 $secureStringPwd = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
 $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $secureStringPwd
 $connection=Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://cys.test.domain.com -Credentials $Credentials

$siteurl = "https://cys.test.domain.com/sites/testsite"
 function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
  $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite "https://cys.test.domain.com"
  $web = Get-SPWeb "https://cys.test.domain.com/sites/testsite"
  foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {

    foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
      #foreach($version in $item.Versions){
        $data = @{
                             "List Name" = $list.Title
                        "Created By" = $item["Author"]
                        "Created Date" = $item["Created"]
                        "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
                        "Modified Date" = $item["Modified"]
                        "Item Name" = $item.File.Name
                        "URL"=$web.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date", "URL"
      }
    #}
    $web.Dispose();
  }
}

Get-DocInventory  | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "d:\test\test.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint 2013 On-Premise, try to install SharePoint 2013 CSOM firstly:

[SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

Then use this script to get list details in a site collection includes sub sites:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl= "http://sp/sites/devtest"
$username="administrator"
$password="******"
$domain="Contoso"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password, $domain)

Try {
    #Function to Get all lists from the web
    Function Get-SPOList($Web)
    {
        #Get All Lists from the web
        $Lists = $Web.Lists
        $Context.Load($Lists)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        #Get all lists from the web  
        ForEach($List in $Lists)
        {
            #Get the List Name
            Write-host $List.Title
            Write-host $List.Created

        }
    }

    #Function to get all webs from given URL
    Function Get-SPOWeb($WebURL)
    {
        #Set up the context
        $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($WebURL)
        $Context.Credentials = $Credentials

        $Web = $context.Web
        $Context.Load($web)
        #Get all immediate subsites of the site
        $Context.Load($web.Webs) 
        $Context.executeQuery()

        #Call the function to Get Lists of the web
        Write-host "Processing Web :"$Web.URL
        Get-SPOList $Web

        #Iterate through each subsite in the current web
        foreach ($Subweb in $web.Webs)
        {
            #Call the function recursively to process all subsites underneaththe current web
            Get-SPOWeb($SubWeb.URL)
        }
    }

    #Call the function to get all sites
    Get-SPOWeb $SiteUrl
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```